# Android Activity Lifecycle for Server Connections Optimization

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm developing an app with chat as a mini feature. I've two chat screens one for conversations listing lets call it ***ActivityA*** and other for actual message sending and reading lets call it ***ActivityB***. The problem is that my chat server can only handle a limited number of concurrent open connections. So, to optimise connections, I'm trying to only connect when user is at any of chat screens and disconnect as soon as the chat screens go away i.e. **stop**ed. For this, I tried using **Activity**'s lifecycle methods **onStart** and **onStop**. I connect on **onStart** and disconnect on **onStop**. The problem is that the **onStop** ***ActivityA*** is called after **onStart** of ***ActivityB***. Hence when user lands on ***ActivityB*** the connection get dismissed and no message can be sent.
How can I fix this issue, please help?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` because that tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to solve this issue would be to use a global state. I.e.: connect to the server once and use the same connection in both activities. This can be done using the `Application` class. Refer to this [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310024716/http://www.intertech.com/blog/androids-application-class/) for more details and examples.

But basically what is going to happen is that you have the connection objects inside of the `globalState` (Can be any name), and you will access it from `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. Thus you wouldn't have to connect to the server again.

Comment: I don't think this solve's OP's problem. He wants to reduce the number of clients connected to the server, so he doesn't want the client connected unless the user is actually using his app. Your solution would have each client permanently connected to the server even if the user wasn't using the app (ie: app in the background).

Comment: Yes indeed you have a point, but the OP's problem was opening and closing the connection depending on the activity, using my answer, he can use the same connection regardless of the activity. But as you have said he must close the connection manually when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do your connect/disconnect in `onResume()` and `onPause()`. These will also be called in each `Activity`, so to avoid breaking things I would delay the disconnect and cancel it if `onResume()` is called within a reasonable amount of time. Something like this:

in `onPause()`:

- Schedule a `Runnable` to disconnect in 500msec

in `onResume()`:

- Cancel any disconnect `Runnable`
- Connect to server